# Why the Gridview backgroundcolor property not retaining on clicking link button in template field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, templatefield

I have **GridView** on an ASP .NET Web Form. This GridView is bound to an **SQLDataSource**. All columns are **TemplateField**. The GridView is inside an **UpdatePanel**. One of the Columns is **DropDownList**. The HTML for this DropDownList is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" onchange="buildDropDown(this)" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[r_cal_M]") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2016-09</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2016-10</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2016-11</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2016-12</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The JavaScript for buildDropDown() Function is:

```
    function buildDropDown(obj) {
    var status = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;

    var ddlReason = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('SELECT')[0];

    switch (status) {
        case "":
            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            row.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            break;
        case "2016-09":
            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(198, 239, 206)";
            row.style.color = "rgb(0, 97, 0)";
            break;
        case "2016-10":
            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(1255, 199, 206)";
            row.style.color = "rgb(156, 0, 6)";
            break;
        case "2016-11":
            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 235, 156)";
            row.style.color = "rgb(156, 101, 0)";
            break;
        case "2016-12":
            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            row.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            break;
    }
}
```

The application is working fine but when I click the **update button** in the GridView the **color** of the row changes **back to original**.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function buildDropDown(obj) {

    var status = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var row = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;

    switch (status) {
        case "":
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            break;
        case "2016-09":
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(198, 239, 206)";
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "rgb(0, 97, 0)"
            break;
        case "2016-10":
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(1255, 199, 206)";
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "rgb(156, 0, 6)";
            break;
        case "2016-11":
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 235, 156)";
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "rgb(156, 101, 0)";
            break;
        case "2016-12":
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
            row.parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            break;
    }
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: @Danish Parvadia Thanks, for your quick response. This is not right. Your code paints the entire GridView and still the backcolor switches to Black on White background if I click the Update Button.

Comment: hope you are doing fine, I am still awaiting your response on this. Regards.